# Examine the convergence of a series as its general limit$(U_n-l)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, general-topology

> We have a sequence $(u_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset \mathbb Q $ where $$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=l\in \mathbb R/\mathbb Q$$
> So :
> $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(u_n-l)\quad \text{is convergent or divergent ?}$$

**Exemlpe**:

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n-e\quad$ is devergent because $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}-e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-e} \right|\succ 1$$

But how can this be proven in the general case, and is there another example that gives this series convergent ?

Comment: What is $\;C_R^{\Bbb Q}\;$ ??

Comment: $\mathrm R/\mathrm Q$

Comment: Did you mean the set of irrational  numbers, $\;\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;$ ?

Comment: $u_n-l$ is the same as $(u_n+r)-(l+r)$ for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$. This can be used to show that the value of the limit $l$ has nothing to do with the convergence of the series you are interested in.

Comment: @FormulaWriter Is this always true?$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(u_n-l)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left((u_n+r)-(l+r)\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(u_n+r)-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(l+r)\quad\text{where}\quad r\in\mathrm R$?

Comment: @Formulawriter       This is what your words tell us mathematically  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n^2}-1+1)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n^2})+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1\implies\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\quad\text{is divergent}$$ This is what you say and it is wrong. Perhaps it can be said that the convergence has nothing to do with the arrangement of the borders, such as$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(u_n-l)=\displaystyle\sum_{\sigma(n)\in S(n)/n\to\infty}(u_n-l)$$

Comment: What I meant is that if you define $v_n=u_n+r$ then $v_n \to l +r $. Calling $L:=l +r$ we have $v_n \to L$ and since $u_n-l=v_n-L$ we have produced a sequence ( the sequence $(v_n)$) with has in general a limit different from that of $u_n$ (for $r \neq 0$ we have $L\neq l$) but for which the series with general term "general term of the sequence minus its limit" behaves in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convergence of the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(u_n-l)$ is linked with "how fast" $u_n$ converges to $l$. Knowing that the limit $l$ is irrational and that the sequence is made with rational numbers does not tell us any information about the convergence of the series considered. In facts, examples can be built in which the series converges and in which it doesn't.

Set $l=\sqrt{2}$, which is irrational.

- Define $u_n =\lfloor10^n\sqrt{2}\rfloor 10^{-n}$. You can show that $u_n \in \mathbb{Q} \; \forall n$, that $u_n\to l$ and that in this case the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(u_n-l)$ converges, since  $|u_n-l|\leq 10^{-n}$
- Consider now $u_n =\lfloor10^n\sqrt{2}\rfloor 10^{-n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$. Still $u_n \in \mathbb{Q} \; \forall n$ and $u_n\to l$ but this time the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(u_n-l)$ diverges since the series has only negative terms and $|u_n-l|\geq \frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: How did you find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\sqrt{2}\text{?}$$

Comment: @Bachamohamed $u_n$ is a compact way to write the approximation of $\sqrt{2}$ up to the $n$-th decimal digit

Comment: @Bachamohamed In other words, for $\sqrt{2}=1,4142135\cdots$  we have:
$$u_0=1$$
$$u_1=1,4$$
$$u_2=1,41$$
$$u_3=1,414$$
$$u_4=1,4142$$
and so on

Comment: thank's @ formulawriter

Comment: @Bachamohamed You are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

$u_n = 1-1/2^n$
makes the sum converge.

$u_n = 1-1/n$
makes the sum diverge.

Both converge to
$l=1$.

Comment: $u_n=1-\frac{1}{2^n}\in\mathrm Q$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=1\notin\mathrm R/\mathrm Q$